# Gradle Exec - how to log commandline?

Tags: java, gradle, exec

I am using Gradle to build my project.
The build file contains several [Exec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) tasks to run external programs (shell scripts and the Java Packager). The build is not always successful and I want to find out why. Analyzing all the output I have it feels strange that Gradle does not print the command that is getting invoked.

How can I make Gradle print the commandline before it starts executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use log levels of gradle

whenever you invoke gradle command you can do like this

```
./gradlew mytask --info //info logs
./gradlew mytask -s //to get stacktrace
```

Ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_logging
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_debugging